# Insert text at specific position in Google Docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

Trying to insert text to a Google Doc. I would like it to be formated as followed:

[image]

Text1

*Space*

Text2

*Space*

I have the following code:

```
function InsertText1() {
   var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
   var text = body.editAsText();
   text.insertText(1, 'This is ju for test, lorem ipsum!');         

}

function InsertText2(){
   var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
   var text = body.editAsText();
   text.insertText(10, 'What test?, lorem ipsum!'); 
}
```

The results from running this, gives us text-in-text and just a mess. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use appendText instead of insertText, like this:

```
text.appendText('This is ju for test, lorem ipsum!\n');
```

And add "\n" to add a 'new row'